# How many copies of the Bible are there per capita?

Tags: bible, united-states, demographics

How many Bibles are in existence, at libraries, warehouses, bookstores, etc.?  Also, how many are being produced annually?  I am primarily interested in the United States, but a worldwide figure would also be appreciated.

In many nations Bibles are hard to come by, because owning even a single page is cause for imprisonment and torture.

Comment: Websites like this one say over 6 billion, but I don't know how reliable it is. http://www.statisticbrain.com/bibles-printed/

Comment: Welcome to C.SE. Sounds like a fair question. But it sounds more like you are making a point. If you have a chance take some time to go over the Help Page for this site.

Comment: Interesting question. Have you also considered the Bible on people's mobile devices?  I have one on mine, plus a few printed copies

Comment: You might find this question interesting and the research related: [Is the IKEA catalogue being distributed in more prints than the Bible?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2543/933)

Answer (score 3):

The latest from [Barna Research](https://www.barna.org/barna-update/culture/664-the-state-of-the-bible-6-trends-for-2014) says there are 4.7 Bibles per household. An interesting [New Yorker article](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2006/12/18/the-good-book-business?currentPage=all) (about how publishers love printing new editions of the Bible) touches on the difficulty of estimating such figures, but gives the printed-per-year number as about 25 million. I'm sure that difficulty would be greatly compounded for international figures given the variety of versions, languages, illegal copies, etc. At any rate, I couldn't find any reliable sources with worldwide figures, but the websites that I have found with figures seem to put it in the .5 to 1 Bible per person ballpark.